# How can I replace in vim in a dynamic way (see description)?

Tags: vim

Can I do a replace like following in vim, if yes, how?

replace `sym_table[<var>]` by `sym_table.get(<var>)`

can be anything, but it should remain same in both initial and final version of file.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic"? What have you tried already? What were the difficulties you had?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:<range>s#sym_table\[\(.*\)\]#sym_table.get(\1)#
```

`\(.*\)` matches and captures anything inside a pair of square brackets, and `\1` is replaced with that match. For more info, see `:help :substitute` and `:help search-pattern`.